# When does the Charisma bonus from Fire Affinity apply?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, sorcerer, ability-scores, racial-traits

Per the [SRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/featured-races/arg-ifrit#TOC-Standard-Racial-Traits):

> **Fire Affinity**: Ifrit sorcerers with the elemental (fire) bloodline treat their Charisma score as 2 points higher for all sorcerer spells and class abilities...

When does that +2 charisma bonus come into play?

For instance:  My Ifrit has a base Charisma of 17, which becomes 19 after I add two for the Ifrit Racial Ability Score Modifiers.  That gives me a +4 Charisma Modifier (was +3 with 17 Charisma)

Do I consider my Charisma to be 21 when calculating the Charisma Modifier for Class Abilities?  Making the Charisma Modifier for those Abilities +5?

Do I consider my Charisma to be 21 when calculating how many [Bonus Spells Per Day](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/ability-scores#TOC-Determine-Bonuses) I can cast?

Do I consider my Charisma Modifier to be 5 when calculating my base Spell DC (for sorcerer spells)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes to all of the above except Bonus Spells**. Your Charisma score is effectively two higher for everything under the Sorcerer class entry. However, while the Bonus Spells per Day feature is referenced in the class entry, it is actually a universal property of ability scores for all spellcasters. Therefore bonus spells do not benefit from the increase in effective Charisma (as discussed [here](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2ohhx?Fire-Affinity)).

"Ability" in this case is probably the wrong term; they should have referred to "features."

Comment: I wish I had found this earlier... http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2ohhx?Fire-Affinity indicates that maybe spells-per-day would NOT be affected by the bonus... Do you have any resources that indicate otherwise?

Comment: Ah! You are right. I forgot that Bonus Spells Per Day isn't a class feature. I will fix it.